# pyODBC: specify location of driver in Windows

Tags: python, sql, windows, dll, pyodbc

Is it possible to specify where pyodbc looks for the SQL driver?

I have a python application which needs the 'SQL Native Client 10.0' driver to connect to a SQL database. So my connection string looks like:

```
dsn = 'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=sa;PWD=mypasswd'

con = pyodbc.connect(dsn) 
with con: 
    #do something
```

One major disadvantage (at least for me) is, that the SQL Native Client 10.0 driver needs to be installed on the machine and that requires admin privileges. However, I want that the user can run my python application without any install.

After a quick research on the internet, it seems that the SQL Native client 10.0 depends on a simple DLL (sqlncli10.dll) which resides in C:\Windows\System32. So is it possible, to tell pyodbc where it should look for the appropriate SQL driver?

As from my understanding, pymssql does something similar (the FreeTDS driver is included in the Python package, so no further driver installation is required). However, in my opinion pyobc is a more stable than pymssql (and the community seems to be more active too), so I would like to use pyodbc to communicate with my database.

Comment: No it's not because pyodbc is a library to specificly connect against Microsofts ODBC driver. It's not possible to specify the location of a driver since ODBC is a engine, not a driver per-sae.
I'd go with a python library instead of a library that uses a microsoft specific driver, unless you really need Microsoft SQL Server features, then it's a good option cause you're locked down to a Win environment anyways.

Comment: I also assume you know what ODBC is and how it works internally in Windows (http://www.stylusstudio.com/images/screenshots/odbc_data_source_administrator.gif this is what it looks like, and that's also where all the black magic happens). Also consider: https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/

Answer (score 1):

If your application actually uses features specific to

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}
```

then that driver needs to be installed *properly* on the client system. However, if you just need basic connectivity to SQL Server then

```
Driver={SQL Server}
```

is included with a standard Windows install and is available to both 32-bit and 64-bit applications.