# Driver for pyodbc: how to specify its location in macOS?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc, vertica

I want to find a way to specify the path of a driver -- or otherwise resolve problem that Pyodbc cannot find a Vertica driver -- for the following Python 3 command with Pyodbc package

```
Pyodbc.connect(...)
```

but I keep getting the error that a Vertica driver 9.0.x cannot be found. I used the installer [here](https://my.vertica.com/download/vertica/client-drivers/) and the installer [here](https://my.vertica.com/client_drivers/9.0.x/9.0.0-1/vertica-odbc-9.0.0-1.mac.pkg) on macOS.

I currently use an alias Vertica in the command but unknown for the Pyodbc connect so apparently some driver file problem, now need to find a way to resolve this.

**How can I specify the location of the driver for pyodbc? Or otherwise resolve why the driver unknown?**

*Updated comments on TaliTedi answer.*

> 1. How to confirm that iODBC is up-to-date?
> 2. How to build pyodbc with links to iODBC?
> 3. The directory `~/Library/ODBC/odbcini` does not exist. How to configure the DNSs?
>
> [image]

*Older pyodbc threads*

> 1. [pyODBC: specify location of driver in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401566/pyodbc-specify-location-of-driver-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

1. Confirm that [iODBC is fully up-to-date](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X).  (Apple ships an outdated version of iODBC in macOS.)
2. Build pyodbc with links to iODBC (not its default of UnixODBC, which is not typical for macOS).
3. Use `iODBC Administrator.app` (`/Applications/iODBC/`) to configure ODBC Data Source Names (DSNs), which will be saved to default files:

   - System DSNs: `/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`
   - User DSNs: `~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`
4. If pyodbc or other tools require `$ODBCINI` environment variable or similar settings, point them to the file(s) noted above.
5. Enjoy.

Comment: Can you clarify the points? Point 1: what did you mean with the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/procedure-calls)? Did you infer to run some command in Python, SQL client or some other place to check iODBC to be up-to-date? Point 2: how to build the pyodbc with links to iODBC? Point 3: how to configure the DSNs with iODBC?

Comment: (1) I'm sorry; copy-and-paste error. Corrected iODBC URL in answer. (2) That should be another Q&A. (3) Don't use File DSNs until/unless you know they're needed; start with System DSNs.

Comment: (1) Thank you. (2) Question now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084708/how-to-build-pyodbc-with-links-to-iodbc-in-macos). (3) DSN, [Data Source Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_source_name)?

Comment: (3) Yes, DSN is an acronym for Data Source Name.