# How to build pyodbc with links to iODBC in macOS?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyodbc, unixodbc, iodbc

In [Driver for pyodbc: how to specify its location in macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027244/driver-for-pyodbc-how-to-specify-its-location-in-macos), [TallTed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48028164/164148) suggested to open question to explain the following

> *Build pyodbc with links to iODBC (not its default of UnixODBC, which is not typical for macOS).*

so now with the focus —

**How can I build pyodbc with links to iODBC (not its default of UnixODBC, which is not typical for macOS)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should/might work in 4.0.23, as it was the way it was done up to pyodbc v3.0.7:

First, in the file `setup.py`, change line 165 from --

```
    settings['libraries'].append('odbc')
```

-- to --

```
    settings['libraries'].append('iodbc')
```

Second, disable/delete lines 178, 179, and 183.

```
        # Add directories for MacPorts and Homebrew.
#       dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/opt/local/include','~/homebrew/include']
#       settings['include_dirs'].extend(dir for dir in dirs if isdir(dir))

        # unixODBC make/install places libodbc.dylib in /usr/local/lib/ by default
        # ( also OS/X since El Capitan prevents /usr/lib from being accessed )
#       settings['library_dirs'] = [ '/usr/local/lib' ]
```

For reference, see the [file `setup.py` as of pyodbc 3.0.7](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/3.0.7/setup.py), starting at line 146

Note: This will use the macos system supplied -- and presumably outdated -- `libiodbc.dylib` in `/usr/lib`. Not sure where the [iODBC Framework](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X) installs the iODBC files, though. Maybe [TallTed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241164/tallted) can comment on this?

Comment: Sorry not to have seen this until now... `/usr/local/iODBC/lib/` is probably the directory you want, instead of `/usr/local/lib/` or `/usr/lib/`.